# Why uglifyjs doesn't remove dead code?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs

For instance, I have the following code:

```
if ("a" !== "a") {
    console.log('really?');
}

var a = 5;
```

Then I write `uglifyjs code.js -o code.min.js`. As a result, I have the following:

```
if("a"!=="a"){console.log("really?")}var a=5;
```

How do I enable removing the dead code inside the if-statement?

Comment: What's the dead code? ``console.log``? or the entire if block? The former is a perfectly valid code with perfectly valid purpose. It is very different than optimizing``if(a == 1 || a == 1)``. Plus I think uglifier does very limited optimization.

Comment: The code inside the if-block will never run. So, it's dead.

Comment: you need static analysis tool, not just AST parser.

Comment: @CppLearner, **you surely need** to know what you're disputing about. Stackoverflow is not the place where you express your thoughts or doubts and especially not the place where you convince others that you know what you actually don't know. UglifyJS2 does dead code removal just perfectly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Despite this question has already got an accepted answer, I think it's worth mentioning that

1. `UglifyJS2` does remove dead code
2. To turn this feature on, you need to set appropriate option either in CLI (`uglifyjs --compress unused,dead_code`) or in the `options` object if you invoke `uglify` programmatically (`uglify(compress: { unused: true, dead_code: true });`).

Comment: For me, I also needed to set evaluate and conditionals to true, and set most other things to false. I only wanted to dead code elimination, not any other compression.

Comment: you can also use `sideEffects` prop in package.json if you are using webpack with uglifyjs, https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#clarifying-tree-shaking-and-sideeffects

Answer (score 5):

As per the [README](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) for uglifyjs, the maintainer has shifted development effort to [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2). The README also says that it only removes:

> some unreachable code and warn about it (code that follows a return,
>   throw, break or continue statement, except function/variable
>   declarations).

Uglify2 does a more comprehensive job. I tested your code on the [demo site](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/#demo) and it does indeed remove the whole if statement. It also supports 'conditional compilation' (or maybe more correctly conditional code removal) by allowing you to define globals at the command line when uglifying.

Comment: Thank you for help! That's the solution for my problem